# How to reference a range of cells in a row

Tags: vba, excel

This is a sample code. I am trying to get values of cells D9, E9 and F9

```
Private Sub test()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = ws1.Range("D9:F" & lastrow )

For Each cell In myRange
    Debug.Print cell
Next cell

End Sub
```

But this cell also consist of values from column G and H. What am I missing?

Comment: could you show the code for `GetLastRow` function code.

Comment: There is no one to answer this ?

Comment: NO ... I didn't get anything outside D and F. Thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get the data for specific cells which you already know the addresses of (D9, E9, F9), you don't need to worry about getting the last row.  Maybe you are trying to ask a different question?  Maybe you want to get all of the data from row 9 to the last used used row for columns D, E, & F?  Anyway, to answer the question asked, here is the modified code that will return the requested values:

```
Sub test()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myRange = ws1.Range("D9:F9")

    For Each cell In myRange
        Debug.Print cell
    Next cell

End Sub
```